# Why string formatting in python not working if I write f?

Tags: python, formatting, code-cleanup

```
name = 'peace'
age = 21
print(f"your name is {name} and your age is {age}")
```

error
File "", line 1
    f"your name is {name} and your age is {age}."

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: f-strings are a python 3 feature. Make sure you're on version 3.6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Python version is older than 3.6 you can not use f-strings because they are added in Python 3.6, but you can use `"{}".format(something)`

```
name = 'peace'
age = 21
print("your name is {} and your age is {}".format(name,age))
```

Also see: [**PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: Thanks for this -- just set up with a Synology DiskStation, and its Python 3 is 3.5.1, and was tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to "downgrade" an f-string so it works in 3.5.